# How oracle jdk can be configured in Google App Engine Flexible environment

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

Google App Engine just states about the usage of openjdk in app.yaml, Like

```
runtime_config:
   jdk: openjdk8
   server: jetty9
```

Reference : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

I want to use oracle jdk. How can I configure app.yaml to use oracle jdk

Note: I am using Google App Engine Flexible environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config you referenced applies to the standard runtimes provided by Google, which does not come with the oracle jdk.

But you can use a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/) instead:

> Use a custom runtime in the App Engine flexible environment to use an
>   alternative implementation of Java, Python, Node.js, or Go, or write
>   code in any other language. Defining new runtime environments allow
>   you to include additional components like language interpreters or
>   application servers.

You'd need to [build it](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build):

> To create a custom runtime you need:
>
> - An `app.yaml` file that describes your application's runtime configuration.
> - A `Dockerfile` that configures the runtime environment. In many cases, this can be just one line specifying a base image.
> - To ensure your application is listening on port 8080 and has request handlers that respond to lifecycle events, such as start, stop, and
>     health check requests.
>
>   **Note: Google supplies base images that you can customize, but you
>     aren't required to use these. You can use other images so long as they
>     satisfy the conditions in the bulleted list above.**

And you'd [configure](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) it like this in your `app.yaml`:

> ```
> runtime: custom
> env: flex
> ```