# How can I get PySoundfile to run on Google Cloud Platform flexible environment?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, audio, google-cloud-platform, libsndfile

I have a simple application that I'd like to deploy to a GAE standard or flexible environment, and it requires the generation of simple audio files.

I have code that runs well locally (on the dev server) using [PySoundfile](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.0/), but I run into errors with the underlying `libsndfile` when the application is deployed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tonegen
  File "/home/vmagent/app/tonegen.py", line 4, in <module>
    import soundfile as sf
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 267, in <module>
    _snd = _ffi.dlopen('sndfile')
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 141, in dlopen
    lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 802, in _make_ffi_library
    backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 797, in _load_backend_lib
    raise OSError(msg)
OSError: ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'sndfile'
```

I've also tried [wave](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the flexible environment you could try to build and use a custom runtime in which you can add non-python dependencies, like OS libraries (`libsndfile` in your case and whatever else you may need).

Basically the same answer as in [How oracle jdk can be configured in Google App Engine Flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48367184/how-oracle-jdk-can-be-configured-in-google-app-engine-flexible-environment/48447259#48447259).

Comment: On this page it says that custom runtimes dont support the GAE APIs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/customizing-the-python-runtime Does this mean that if we use this approach we can't use the GCP datastore?

Comment: I *think* it means you can't use the `ndb` client library (true for the non-custom flex apps too). But the datastore can be used (with the generic client library) from any python app, even from outside the google cloud, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49124207/4495081.

Comment: This worked. Used GAE flex + a custom python runtime based on gcr.io/google-appengine/python which allowed use of the datastore, flask, as well as installation of the needed libs.